# Loading Remote Groovy Script

Tags: java, groovy

I'm loading a Groovy script/class from a remote server, creating a new instance, and invoking a method, as shown below:

```
String[] scriptUrls = { "http://10.74.192.186/groovy/Test.groovy" };

GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptUrls);

Class groovyClass = gse.loadScriptByName("Test.groovy");

GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
Object[] callArgs = {};

System.out.println(groovyObject.invokeMethod("getTest", callArgs));
```

How is the Groovy file compiled to bytecode when pulled off a server like this?  Do I only need a JRE to run this?

I'm just a little confused how this works internally.

For reference, here is the Groovy file:

```
class Test {
    String test = "test"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Groovy file is compiled with the Groovy compiler, no JDK is needed (Groovy compiles directly to bytecode).